# Show Welcome message when logging in first time

Tags: php, mysql

When a user registers and logs in for first time, I want to show them a welcome message or some tooltips.

An approach can be used where we create cookies, but what if the user clears his browser cookies?

I am using PHP.

Comment: Show what you have (tried) so far. We won' t do everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can save in database field on user data value if user has logged in already. 
Or more general you can save last login date - if it's empty - user didn't log in yet.
if not - show tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field in the database with a 1 or 0 value that would indicate if someone has seen the welcome message.

0 = not Seen
1 = Seen

Answer (score 0):

In an office situation where users have their own computers with static ip's, you could store the user's IP ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) in your database.  If the entry exists, do not show message/tooltips.  If it does not exist, show message and add to database.